# Change file content using batch

Tags: batch-file

So I have this going and I need a little help to improve it

```
@ECHO Off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
cd /d "%~dp0"
:: Significant part of string

set "replacemain="appi": "

@For %%G In ("%~dp0Originals") Do Set "sourcedir=%%~fG"
@For %%G In ("%~dp0Ready") Do Set "destdir=%%~fG"

FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN ('dir /b /s /a-d "%sourcedir%\(*)*.txt"') DO (
 rem calculate new destination directory
 SET "newdest=%%~dpq"
 SET "newdest=!newdest:%sourcedir%=%destdir%!"
 SET "newdest=!newdest:~0,-1!"
 MD "!newdest!" 2>nul

(
 FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=()" %%j IN ("%%~nxq") DO (
  rem %%j now has sequence number
  for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "%%q"') do (
   set "line=%%b"
   if defined line IF "%%b" neq "!line:appi=!" CALL :subs %%j
   echo(!line!
  )
 )
)>"!newdest!\%%~nxq" 

)
GOTO :eof

:: substitute
:subs
SET "original=%line%"
FOR /L %%s IN (0,1,9) DO set "line=!line:%replacemain%%%s=%replacemain%!"
IF "%original%" neq "%line%" goto subs
set "line=!line:%replacemain%=%replacemain%%1!"
GOTO :eof
```

This is designed to read anything in the filename in closed by ( )

```
Main Folder
|
+-\Orignal
|--| + - (100) Craft.txt
|--------------"appi": 4748483,
+-\Ready
|--| + - (100) Craft.txt
|--------------"appi": 100,
```

My script is based on 1 code editing and now I have been trying to change it to multiple code editing

As you can see here, this is set for one code I would like to change it to a type of dictionary

```
set "replacemain="appi": "
```

My goal

```
replace=replacemain = ("appi":
                       "code":
                       "gedt":)

set "replace"

if defined line IF "%%b" neq "!line:replace=!" CALL :subs %%j
       echo(!line!
```

Could this be possible, and all codes will change to match the file name in the (?)

Also is there a way to increase the speed of the script

Thank you

This is how it looks inside my txt file

```
BEFORE
(100) filename.txt
    |----"appi": 4748483,
         "code": 415241,
         "gedt": 458421,

AFTER
(100) filename.txt
    |----"appi": 100,
         "code": 100,
         "gedt": 100,
```

Comment: Concerning the speed: It can mostly not be improved because of the `dir /s` command. Depending on the depth of the subdirectories, the number of files and the volume size of the disk you're searching on. So can it be improved? Maybe, if you make some changes to the logic. Then on the replacement. I am a little in the dark as to what you require, are you saying the replacement string should be the lines with the line breaks included as per the code in the goal statement? if so, yes it is possible, but I'll need some clarity on the requirement first.

Comment: @Gerhard - so this script is a 1 code at a time content editor it copies from source to target, and while it copies it edits the txt file, it finds the code in the file and replaces it with the code of my desire, for a while now only one code was needed to edit, but now with recent updates, I have multiple codes to replace at the same time, so what I did for now was made copies of the script and assigned each script their own code to find and edit, so my goal now is to make a list of codes like a dictionary, so if I have to add extra codes I can, all codes look like this `"gdjh": 12545,`

Comment: ok, so basically have a list of search items and a list of replace items? in other words, replace all `gdhf` with `abcd` and all `1234` with `5678` etc?

Comment: Now the way it works it reads the file name  example `(100) filename.txt` and finds the number inside the `( )` so the number tells the script what to use to update the codes with, now I was trying to convert it to an internal code list where it will scan files find the matching file name and edits the txt with codes entered like this `Code_list=( (1), 100,` this could be on the inside, to where it doesn't need to take the number on the filename anymore, the `(1)` represents the filename, and the `100` represent the replacement number, hopefully it makes sense, I know I can chat away

Comment: well yes, but the original code will have random numbers `set "replacemain="appi": "` as you see here after the `:` it blank, they all carry random numbers, and the script will find the number in the `(100)` and update it in the txt file, this is how it looks inside the txt file `"appi": 12458,` and it will change to '"appi": 100,`

Comment: @Gerhard - I have updated my question and added a better look to the txt files, each txt file will have the same codes, but all will have random numbers leading after it, so the script will overwrite any data leading after this `:` and before this `,`

Comment: ok, I see. So then set the search parameters as something like `set "params=appi code gedt"` then run a loop again like: `for %%x in (%params%) do if defined line IF "%%b" neq "!line:%%x=!" CALL :subs %%j`

Comment: so the script reads this `set "replacemain="appi": "` the `replacemain` is in the script, so do I change the `params to replacemain` or do I change the script to read the `params`

Comment: `set "params="appi": "code": "gedt":"`

Comment: `FOR /L %%s IN (0,1,9) DO set "line=!line:%replacemain%%%s=%replacemain%!"` will change to this `FOR /L %%s IN (0,1,9) DO set "line=!line:%params%%%s=%params%!"`

Comment: @Gerhard -  this part failed set `"params="appi": "code": "gedt": "` - this worked with all the changes made set `"params="appi": "`

Comment: OK, I made some changes and found how to make it work, I know I did it wrong, but it works, I repeated the `set` I made 3 sets like this `set "params1="code1": "` and `set "params2="code2": "` and so on

Comment: and repeated this `for %%x in (%params%) do if defined line IF "%%b" neq "!line:%%x=!"` Thank you very much

Comment: @Gerhard - I do need help with 1 more thing, very few codes look like this `set "params="appi": -124585"` it has a negative in it, and the script fails to edit it correctly, what is the best way to add a way to replace that as well, this happens `set "params="appi": 100-124585,`